# Calling a copy constructor in Presenter to prepare a list of Models

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dependency-injection, mvp

I'm new to MVP. In a presenter I have following code. Here what am I trying is to create a list of `Model` objects (in this case `IAttendance` objects) and to show them on a `DataGridView` in the `View`.

Every time an attendance is entered on the View, `AddAttendanceObjectToGrid()` method on the presenter will be called to add the new attendance to the list. So to add a new Attendance model to the list I'm using a copy constructor in my Model.

Now this code runs giving the desired output but I feel this could be further improved to get the best of MVP.

```
class AttendancePresenter : BasePresenter
{
    private IAttendance _Model;
    private readonly IAttendanceView _View;

    BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();
    List<IAttendance> AttendanceList = new List<IAttendance>();

    public AttendancePresenter( IAttendance model, IAttendanceView view )
    {
        _Model = model;
        _View = view;
    }

    private void AddAttendanceObjectToGrid()
    {
        SetModelPropertiesFromView(_Model, _View); // Call base class method to update the Model with data
        IAttendance attendanceModel = new Attendance(_Model); // Use copy constructor to get a new copy of model
        AttendanceList.Add(attendanceModel); // Add new model to list
        BS.DataSource = AttendanceList; // Show list on the grid
        _View.AttendanceInGrid = BS;
    }
}
```

**MY MODEL**

```
class Attendance : IAttendance
    {
        public string PointID { get; set; }
        public string PointName { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public DateTime InTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime OutTime { get; set; }
        public string ShiftType { get; set; }

        public Attendance() // Default constructor
        {
        }

        public Attendance(IAttendance attendance) //Copy constructor
        {
            PointID = attendance.PointID;
            PointName = attendance.PointName;
            EmployeeID = attendance.EmployeeID;
            EmployeeName = attendance.EmployeeName;
            InTime = attendance.InTime;
            OutTime = attendance.OutTime;
            ShiftType = attendance.ShiftType;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you copy the model before putting it in the `List`?

Comment: @Ocelot20, If I remove that, then each time a reference to same object will be added to the list. Eventually I'll have identical objects in the list (the one added last)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, there seems to be something off in the structure.

You wish to display a list of `IAttendance` objects on the screen. To me, this means that the Model is a list of `IAttendance` objects but the code shows only a single `IAttendance` instance being passed into the constructor.  How do you get more than one item into the presenter?

It has been a long while since I used MVX under WinForms, so some of what I remember may be off, but I would have a Model consisting of a list of `IAttendance` objects (not a single object) and just add them to a `BindingList`.  There should be no need to copy the objects. (If you want to edit them, make them implement `IEditableObject`).

**Bottom Line** 
There should be no need to copy the objects just to show them in a list.
If you want the screen to display a list of objects then the Model should consist of a list of objects, not a single one 
If you want to edit the objects, implementing `IEditableObject` is a better path than copying/saving and restoring on cancel.

Comment: If I explain a bit... Basically my model is an `IAttendance` object as User enter one attendance at a time on the `View`. I just want to maintain a list of entered attendance on the view (in a data grid) so that user can verify the list before saving them. Then should be two `Models`?

Comment: @Chaturanga There is only one model for the screen though it may contain many elements. If you want a list of items to be on the screen then the model should contain that list. It sounds like you should have a List of `IAttendance`  and then a single one (call it CurrentAttendance or SelectedAttendance)  Without talking through the requirements/design it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: Ok then 1). If I add a List<IAttendance) to my `IAttendance` model itself, I don't have to create a list in my presenter rather I could call `_Model.AttendanceList.Add();` 2). Or else I have to have a new Model call it `ListModel` and it has only an instance of `List<IAttendance> AttendanceList;` So in this case `IAttendance` is only a type not a model. But still I don't see how to add new instances to the list without calling a copy constructor or some cloning method as we are working with references?

Comment: I think I see the problem.  You are working continually with one `IAttendance` instance and copying it across after populating.  Another way to approach this is to 'move' across the instance with which you have been working and then create a new instance when the user inputs the details of the next attendance.  I would push for this shape; it means no worries about a copy/clone and guarantees that you start off with a fresh instance for the next input.